# SQL Server : sum a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried everything I could to get the `Current` column added up. 'BF', 'Current' and 'Future' should all equal zero and I just need a quick check to verify it.

The code

```
SELECT 
    [AccountCode], [ExpensesCode], [CostCentre],
    [NLYear], [NLPeriod],
    SUM([BroughtForward]) AS 'BF',
    SUM([CurrentPostings]) AS 'Current',
    SUM([FuturePostings]) AS 'Future',
    [Company]
FROM 
    [A_DW].[dbo].[NEW_ETL AccBalance]
WHERE
    [Company] = 'GAR' 
    AND NLPeriod = '3' AND NLYear = '2017'
GROUP BY
    [AccountCode], [ExpensesCode], [CostCentre], [NLYear], [NLPeriod], [Company]
```

This is Autoline database, and the data is a trial balance, so looks as follows:

```
+-----+------+-----+------+---+---------+---------+------+    
| 100 | 8000 | 700 | 2017 | 3 | 1000.00 | 2000.00 | 0.00 |
| 100 | 8001 | 700 | 2017 | 3 | 1500.00 | 4500.00 | 0.00 |
+-----+------+-----+------+---+---------+---------+------+
```

Result should 6500.00 (2000.00 + 4500.00)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also tag with the database you are using.  And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: What's the column type for those 3 columns? I don't really see anything wrong at this point.

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am fairly confident this is MS SQL Server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Seems to be Sql server.

Comment: Hi, Yes it is MSSQL Server.

Comment: The 'Current' field is a numeric field

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  You said you need a quick check to verify the result of the query is 0.  Did you run the query?  What did you get?

Comment: So  I would like to have just a single row with a total for the 'BF' 'Current' and 'Future'. Currently I get a detailed trial balance.

Comment: @Herman Remove the `[ExpensesCode]`. you get the result as Expected

Comment: I cant remove the ExpensesCode, it needs to be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample data, your column `ExpenseCode` has multiple different values in it. If you want to collapse these two rows together, you need to decide what to do with that column. Here's one option: ignore it!

```
SELECT 
    [AccountCode],
    --[ExpensesCode], --comment it out, or delete entirely
    [CostCentre],
    [NLYear], [NLPeriod],
    SUM([BroughtForward]) AS 'BF',
    SUM([CurrentPostings]) AS 'Current',
    SUM([FuturePostings]) AS 'Future',
    [Company]
FROM 
    [A_DW].[dbo].[NEW_ETL AccBalance]
WHERE
    [Company] = 'GAR' 
    AND NLPeriod = '3' AND NLYear = '2017'
GROUP BY
    [AccountCode],
    --[ExpensesCode], -- also comment out here
    [CostCentre],
    [NLYear],
    [NLPeriod],
    [Company]
```

Comment: This still doesnt leave one line for me

Comment: Other than the 'sum' columns, what else differs between the rows in the output? If nothing does, you have something unwanted in your `group by` clause. If something does differ you need to do that same to that field as we did with `ExpenseCode`.

Comment: In one of your comments above you said you need `ExpensesCode` in the final output. But from the data you provided there were different values in that field. If you only want a single row on your output you need to decide how to handle this. What should show for this field in your single row of output? Same question goes for anything else which differs across the rows but 'must be shown'. Please show us a full version of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows you are getting is equal to the number of distinct combination of :  **[AccountCode], [ExpensesCode], [CostCentre], [NLYear], [NLPeriod]**

In case you need a single row, just remove those columns from the query and leave the **sum** columns.

Query can be :

```
SELECT 
    SUM([BroughtForward]) AS 'BF',
    SUM([CurrentPostings]) AS 'Current',
    SUM([FuturePostings]) AS 'Future'
FROM 
    [A_DW].[dbo].[NEW_ETL AccBalance]
WHERE
    [Company] = 'GAR' 
    AND NLPeriod = '3' AND NLYear = '2017'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, it still doesnt help. If I delete all of these, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword FROM"

Comment: I included the new query in the answer, check it.